# super expression must either be null or a function at Object._inherits

Tags: javascript, class, import

when i try to import a class( with super initialize) in to another class, i get this error

> super expression must either be null or a function Object._inherits

and my code doesnt work,
below is imported class

```
export default class ToDo extends Editor{
#toDoEditor = null;
initialize(id, settings): void
{
    super.initialize(id, settings);
    this.#createEditor();
}}
```

Any hints at all as to what is wrong would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
export default class ToDo extends Editor{
#toDoEditor = null;
constructor(id, settings){
  super()
  this.initialize(id, settings);
}
initialize(id, settings): void{
    // logic
    this.#createEditor();
}}
// import ToDo
let sc = new ToDo(id, setting)
```

Comment: thanks, ofcourse dude i cant do this because, i want to import this class into another class and i cant change this class(just, i have to import, not change)